# MySQL doesent sort by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to run this query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `official_holiday` ORDER BY `official_holiday`.`date` desc";
```

I even generated the query with PHPMyAdmin just to be sure its correct. I dont why it does not order at all and just takes the dates as they are in the DB.

How can I order by date? I just want to echo the results with the smallest date first from the fetched result array.

Thanks in advance

E//
[image]

Comment: Please show sample data and the results you are getting.  Also, is `official_holiday.date` properly stored as a `date` data type.

Comment: Please show your  **date format or data type**

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added a screenshot

Comment: @Rahautos I added a screenshot

Comment: change desc to DESC and try again @Gintoki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query like this

```
SELECT * FROM `official_holiday` ORDER BY DATE(`official_holiday`.`date`) desc.
```

It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `official_holiday` ORDER BY date DESC.
```

This should work, as long as your dates are stored in the correct format.

Nice and simple.